# schedule a DMS task thru task scheduler- first we need to stop the running task and then start it

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, dms

I have setup a DMS task with "FULL LOAD + CDC ". as far as i know if we have created a new table in our source MYSQL RDS then that would be migrated to the target REDSHIFT cluster only when we stop and resume the task. is there any alternate to this so that newly created table can be migrated without stopping and resuming the DMS task.

Also, i was considering to use the task scheduler to run the DMS task. however the concern here is - since the DMS task will be continuously running, do we have any way to first stop the DMS task and then start it thru windows task scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be use a lambda function .

You can have Event Bridge to schedule your lambda that can get MySql table count .
If you have extra table then same lambda can be used to Stop DMS and then resume DMS task .

Please remember the Lambda Function has to be inside same VPC and subnet where your DMS task is running and also RDS .

Comment: Thanks Sudarshan for the reply.appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sudarshan,

i have created two DMS task(full load+CDC) with RDS MYSQL read replica as source endpoint and REDSHIFT as target endpoint.

one task with only 3 tables is running fine while another task with 400+ tables is failing with this error-

"Last Error Error 1236 reading binary log. Task error notification received  Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL".

i have increased the log retention period of source endpoint to 72 hrs and also made required changes to the parameter group.
how come one task with smaller no. of tables is running fine while another task.
please help.